# I'm trying to create a currency conversion program with c++, I don't know how to continue

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Convert(int dollars)
{
    int amount = dollars * 113;
    cin >> dollars;
} 

int main ()
{
    Convert ();
    count << "Enter the amount you want to convert";
}
```

Comment: I think you are doing things here at the wrong time. 
You are first calling Convert() function without a passed parameter, so the calculation will fail. You could call the cin >> dollars; in your main function before then calling the convert function, but this time using the inputted value as a parameter for it. The function should then return the result.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your program, first it is expecting an argument which you are not supplying, move `cin` to main and send the input to `Convert()` function. Then, return the conversion and print it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Convert(int dollars)
{
    return (dollars * 113);
} 

int main ()
{
    int amount;
    cout << "Enter the amount you want to convert and press enter ";
    cin >> amount;
    cout << "Result is = " << Convert(amount) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```